# ChrW() for using phonetics IPA in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can we get the number for ChrW() when we want to use phonetics IPA in VBA?
Can you tell me the list with numbers for phonetics to pronounce English?

Comment: This seems to be a question about IPA and not about VBA?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_Extensions

Comment: In programs based on the RichEdit control (like Wordpad) you can get the hexadecimal code of a character by placing the cursor after it and pressing *Alt+Shift+X*. It will change into the code. Press *Alt+X* to change a hexadecimal number to a character. EG placing the cursor after ɐ and pressing *Alt+Shift+X* will change ɐ to 250. Pressing *Alt+X* will change 250 to ɐ. Note you can also select the character or number. To use in Basic `ChrW(&h250)` (`&h` means it a hexadecimal number).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to [AscW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.ascw?view=net-6.0).

Microsoft Definition:

> AscW: Returns an integer value representing the character code corresponding to a character.

Here I use the data from [IPA Extensions Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_Extensions) to build a function that will return a collection to lookup the IPA codes:

```
Function MapIPACodes() As Collection
    Set MapIPACodes = New Collection
    With MapIPACodes
        .Add ChrW(592), 324
        .Add ChrW(593), 305
        .Add ChrW(594), 313
        .Add ChrW(595), 160
        .Add ChrW(596), 306
        .Add ChrW(597), 182
        .Add ChrW(598), 106
        .Add ChrW(599), 162
        .Add ChrW(600), 397
        .Add ChrW(601), 322
        .Add ChrW(602), 327
        .Add ChrW(603), 303
        .Add ChrW(604), 326
        .Add ChrW(606), 395
        .Add ChrW(607), 108
        .Add ChrW(608), 166
        .Add ChrW(609), 110
        .Add ChrW(610), 112
        .Add ChrW(611), 141
        .Add ChrW(612), 315
        .Add ChrW(613), 171
        .Add ChrW(614), 147
        .Add ChrW(615), 175
        .Add ChrW(616), 317
        .Add ChrW(617), 399
        .Add ChrW(618), 319
        .Add ChrW(619), 209
        .Add ChrW(620), 148
        .Add ChrW(621), 156
        .Add ChrW(622), 149
        .Add ChrW(623), 316
        .Add ChrW(624), 154
        .Add ChrW(625), 115
        .Add ChrW(626), 118
        .Add ChrW(627), 117
        .Add ChrW(628), 120
        .Add ChrW(629), 323
        .Add ChrW(630), 312
        .Add ChrW(631), 398
        .Add ChrW(632), 126
        .Add ChrW(633), 151
        .Add ChrW(634), 181
        .Add ChrW(635), 152
        .Add ChrW(636), 206
        .Add ChrW(637), 125
        .Add ChrW(638), 124
        .Add ChrW(640), 123
        .Add ChrW(641), 143
        .Add ChrW(642), 136
        .Add ChrW(643), 134
        .Add ChrW(644), 164
        .Add ChrW(646), 204
        .Add ChrW(647), 201
        .Add ChrW(648), 105
        .Add ChrW(649), 318
        .Add ChrW(650), 321
        .Add ChrW(651), 150
        .Add ChrW(652), 314
        .Add ChrW(653), 169
        .Add ChrW(654), 157
        .Add ChrW(655), 320
        .Add ChrW(656), 137
        .Add ChrW(657), 183
        .Add ChrW(658), 135
        .Add ChrW(659), 205
        .Add ChrW(660), 113
        .Add ChrW(661), 145
        .Add ChrW(662), 203
        .Add ChrW(663), 202
        .Add ChrW(664), 176
        .Add ChrW(665), 121
        .Add ChrW(666), 396
        .Add ChrW(667), 168
        .Add ChrW(668), 172
        .Add ChrW(669), 139
        .Add ChrW(670), 291
        .Add ChrW(671), 158
        .Add ChrW(672), 167
        .Add ChrW(673), 173
        .Add ChrW(674), 174
        .Add ChrW(675), 212
        .Add ChrW(676), 214
        .Add ChrW(677), 216
        .Add ChrW(678), 211
        .Add ChrW(679), 213
        .Add ChrW(680), 215
        .Add ChrW(681), 602
        .Add ChrW(682), 603
        .Add ChrW(683), 604
        .Add ChrW(685), 601
    End With

End Function
```

The trick is to create a function that will print out the code for the lookup function:

[[image: Result]

```
 Sub Prep()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Range(Range("A2"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            Debug.Print ".Add ChrW("; AscW(Cell.Value); "),", Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```